# adding time to date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, types

I have a date column I need to take the time portion and add it to another date in a query like

```
date_col + to_char(date_col2,      'HH24:MI:SS')
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

```
date_col + (date_col2 - TRUNC(date_col2))
```

(**note - the parentheses are necessary above!**) is one way, or you can use `TO_DSINTERVAL()`:

```
date_col + TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || TO_CHAR(date_col2, 'HH24:MI:SS'))
```

The value `0` that I am prepending here is the number of days (you need a day value for the `TO_DSINTERVAL()` function - in this case the value is zero).