# Time stored in VARCHAR field Add to Date for Date/Time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a StartTime that is stored in an Oracle db as a Varchar.  I also have a date field.  I'd like to create a Date/Time field.  Can I please have help combining these two?  Much appreciated!

My time field is like this:

```
SITE_START_TIME
11:05
01:23
09:30
09:40
12:30
```

My Date Field is like this:

```
09-SEP-21
21-SEP-21
30-SEP-21
10-SEP-21
01-SEP-21
```

Comment: What data type is your date column?

Comment: Thank for fixing my post @MatBailie!
The date field is a Date type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar question to... [adding time to date in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767395/adding-time-to-date-in-oracle)

Which gives...

```
date_column + to_dsinterval('0 ' || site_start_time || ':00')
```

Comment: Mat,
I get this error on the code you suggested:
The character string you specified is not a valid interval.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be

```
to_date( to_char( date_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) || ' ' || site_start_time,
         'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi' );
```

You could use the string to generate an interval and add that to the actual date as well

```
date_column +
  to_dsInterval( '0 ' || site_start_time || ':00' )
```

Note that an Oracle `date` always has a day and a time component.  So it doesn't really make sense to store a day and a time in separate columns.  Just store the actual `date` value in the `date` column complete with the time.

Comment: Justin, <br/>
Tell me about it!  I asked the programmer why the time is stored as a text field.  I couldn't get him to correct this.

Comment: How do I break the lines?? on here??

Comment: @ScottW - I'm not sure what line breaks you're asking about

Comment: @ScottW You can't use line breaks in comments.  Some formatting works, most doesn't and is limited to use in questions and answers only.